# Split string into list of floats

Tags: python, string, split

I have a string that looks like this :

```
'-300.0,120.0; -186.0,120.0; -106.0,80.0; -78.0,55.0; -57.0,40.0; -29.0,15.0; -10.0,15.0; 10.0,-11.0; 19.0,-11.0; 28.0,-12.0; 57.0,-27.5; 78.0,-37.0; 106.0,-50.0; 150.0,-70.0; 186.0,-90.0; 236.0,-110.0; 300.0,-120.0'
```

I want to do a scatter plot, having on the X axis numbers before the column and on the Y axis numbers after the column. Each pair is separated by ';'.

I have numerous strings like this in a list, so I cannot use a `read_csv` or function like this.

Is there a way to format this into a list of tuple ? Or 2 lists ?

Thanks

Comment: Try [str.split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [float](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=float#float)

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far (forming a [mcve]), example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, one-liner. Split according to `;`, then iterate on those strings, and split/convert to float, force iteration in a `tuple` for instance:

```
s = '-300.0,120.0; -186.0,120.0; -106.0,80.0; -78.0,55.0; -57.0,40.0; -29.0,15.0; -10.0,15.0; 10.0,-11.0; 19.0,-11.0; 28.0,-12.0; 57.0,-27.5; 78.0,-37.0; 106.0,-50.0; 150.0,-70.0; 186.0,-90.0; 236.0,-110.0; 300.0,-120.0'

tuples = [tuple(float(y) for y in x.split(",")) for x in s.split(";")]

print(tuples)
```

or using `map`, slightly faster, and works on python 3 because of forced iteration to `tuple`:

```
tuples = [tuple(map(float,x.split(","))) for x in s.split(";")]
```

result:

```
[(-300.0, 120.0), (-186.0, 120.0), (-106.0, 80.0), (-78.0, 55.0), (-57.0, 40.0), (-29.0, 15.0), (-10.0, 15.0), (10.0, -11.0), (19.0, -11.0), (28.0, -12.0), (57.0, -27.5), (78.0, -37.0), (106.0, -50.0), (150.0, -70.0), (186.0, -90.0), (236.0, -110.0), (300.0, -120.0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the plotting part for the sake of completion:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s = '-300.0,120.0; -186.0,120.0; -106.0,80.0; -78.0,55.0; ' \
    '-57.0,40.0; -29.0,15.0; -10.0,15.0; 10.0,-11.0; 19.0,-11.0; ' \
    '28.0,-12.0; 57.0,-27.5; 78.0,-37.0; 106.0,-50.0; 150.0,-70.0; ' \
    '186.0,-90.0; 236.0,-110.0; 300.0,-120.0'

v = [tuple(map(float, t.split(","))) for t in s.split("; ")]

plt.scatter(*zip(*v))
plt.show()
```

To get two separate sequences:

```
x, y = zip(*v)

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Or:

```
x = [w[0] for w in v]
y = [w[1] for w in v]

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Or:

```
x = [a for a, b in v]
y = [b for a, b in v]

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```